# Cakebake not working

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp-2.4.4 When I have backed my project in console this giving me below error

[image]

myphp version :5.4.12 
If any body face this types of problem.Please help me to solve it.
I can ensure there is no any problem in environment variable.I have checked.

Comment: did you add cake path in environment variables ?

Comment: Of-course I added.My all project running in wamp server without cake project.I have try by a project that have already done.Now after run this project I get this error "Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

Comment: also please verify php path

Comment: I have verified.I am not new in cakephp.I have already done many project by cakephp.But this error is new for me.

Comment: Do not add cake to the environment. And always call your cake shell relative to your app dir. then it will always work out of the box. Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Bake is run in Console directory.Try in app/Console

Answer (score 0):

### Call *Console* cake

In the early days it was recommended to put cake in your path so you could type `cake` anywhere. Eventually this was realised to be a bad idea, it's not the recomended way to do things any more instead use the executable that's *in* your application:

```
> cd my\app
> Console\cake

Welcome to CakePHP v2.x.x Console
---------------------------------...
```

### Read the error message

If using the correct executable doesn't immediately fix the problem - *read the error message*. It's not possible to say more as the image in the question truncates the output, however it contains:

```
<title>... Errors</title>
```

This in an indication that the output is a cakephp error i.e. the html you're seeing is the result of a fatal error of some kind (e.g. a missing plugin, model or other class).

Read the error message (or open `app\tmp\error.log` and read it there), address the problem and Console\cake will work as expected.

Comment: I still don't know why this problem have occurred, After remove all path from environment variable I have re-type php,mysql and project console path again.I also have changed my php version.I think this problem happen for php.But I am not sure.after change php version it have worked fine.

Comment: If you don't read and show a relevant error message - nobody can help you :).